# How to write nested query MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a page to edit board meetings and I want to display all board members who ***did not attend*** specific meeting as a checkox located below who attend as an edit in case of user want to add more so I did this:

My code:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `boardteam`";
    $r = mysql_query($q);
    while ($dbfield = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
    {
        $member_id =$dbfield['nationalID'];
        $query = "SELECT `attendance` FROM `meetingattendance` WHERE `meetingID` = '$mid' AND `attendance`!= '$member_id'";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if ($res)
        {
        $tname ="";
        switch ($dbfield['titleName'])
        {
            case "Dr":
            $tname .= "د.";
            break;
            case "Ms":
            $tname .= "السيدة.";
            break;
            case "Mr":
            $tname .= "السيد.";
            break;
        }
        $At .= "<input type='checkbox' name='moreAttendence[]' dir='rtl' value=".$dbfield['nationalID']."><div class='styled-checkbox'>".$tname." ".$dbfield['fName']." ".$dbfield['sName']." ".$dbfield['lName']."</div><br>";
        }

    }
```

DB:

```
CREATE TABLE `boardteam` (
`nationalID` int(10) NOT NULL,
`titleName` char(2) NOT NULL,
`fName` char(20) NOT NULL,
`sName` char(20) NOT NULL,
`lName` char(20) NOT NULL,
`gender` char(1) NOT NULL,
`birthDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`materialStatus` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`jobTitle` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`jobLocation` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`employer` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`photo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`academicGrade` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`employmentStartDate` date NOT NULL,
`employmentEndDate` date NOT NULL,
`employmentType` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
`employmentStatus` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`jobStartDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`jobNumber` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`cv` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`nationalID`)
)


CREATE TABLE `meetingattendance` (
 `meetingID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `attendance` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `absence` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `additionalAttendance` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 KEY `absence` (`absence`),
 KEY `meeingID` (`meetingID`),
 KEY `attendance` (`attendance`),
 CONSTRAINT `meetingattendane_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`meetingID`) REFERENCES `boardmeetings` (`meetingID`),
 CONSTRAINT `meetingattendane_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`attendance`) REFERENCES `boardteam` (`nationalID`),
 CONSTRAINT `meetingattendane_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`absence`) REFERENCES `boardteam` (`nationalID`)
)
```

With my code I got all board members including who attend, How to fix that ??

Comment: Don't write nested queries, that's highly inefficient: write a single query using a JOIN between the two tables

Comment: First of all please use mysqli_* because mysql_* is deprecated. and how to use multi-query in php take a look of this nice example:- http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp. But correct way to do this is Join.

Comment: more specifically, an outer join to find values that don't match

Comment: Thank You guys for the rich Information you gave me many lessons ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` in order to find people in the boardTeam who were not in a specific meeting. eg:

```
SELECT b.*, m.attendance
  FROM boardTeam b
    LEFT JOIN meetingattendance m
      ON b.nationalID = m.attendance AND m.meetingID = $mid
    WHERE m.meetingID IS NULL
```

If you want to get ALL board members, and then determine within PHP if they attended the meeting or not, simply remove the `m.attendance IS NULL` clause, as such:

```
SELECT b.*, m.attendance as attendance
  FROM boardTeam b
    LEFT JOIN meetingattendance m
      ON b.nationalID = m.attendance AND m.meetingID = $mid
```

and now when you loop through the response rows in php, you can test as such (assuming you fetch your rows one by one into a $row variable):

```
if($row['attendance'] != null)
{
  // attended meeting
}
else
{
  // did not attend meeting
}
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, use mysqli, or pdo instead of pure mysql_ functions

Example fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba7d4/6

Comment: Thank you so much ,, I will rewrite all my nested queries ^^